# Setting up the standard matrix for orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, transformation

> For a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, you are given these three ordered bases:
>
> $A= (\mathbf{a}=(1,-2,-1,3), \mathbf{b}=(1,3,-2,-4))$
>
> $B= (\mathbf{a}=(1,-2,-1,3), \mathbf{c}=(2,1,-3,-1))$
>
> $C= (\mathbf{b}=(1,3,-2,4), \mathbf{d}=(0,5,-1,-7))$
>
> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $V$.
>
> $a)$ Explain why $T$ is or is not invertible.
>
> $b)$ Find the matrix $[T]$ which represents $T$ with respect to the standard coordinates.

I really need some guidance with this... Why isn't the matrix invertible? Is it because the matrix $T$ is not a square matrix?

For part $b)$, how do I do it? I tried to use the projection formula $[T]=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ but the matrix isn't invertible...

How do I approach this? I'm very much stumped on this.

Comment: $T$ has better be square since it represents a map from $\mathbb R^4$ into itself. Think about the rank of $T$.

Comment: Ohh yeah. Point made. Is it not invertible since the matrix is not onto? The transformation takes vectors in 4D space and spits out a vectors which span a 2D space which does span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

If that's nonsense, how does the rank work? Rank+nullity=dimension. So that would mean $4+nullity=4$ and thus $nullity=0$. Woudn't that mean the matrix **IS** invertible though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a linear transformation from $A^m\to B^n$, where $m,n$ are dimensions of $A,B$ respectively, has a matrix of order $n\times m$. Thus, $T:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$ is a linear map having a $4\times4$ **square** matrix, $[T]$.

For showing that $T$ is not invertible, you can show that there is an element in $\ker(T)$ other than $(0,0,0,0)$, that is, $\dim(\ker(T))>0$. For example, $\mathbf u=(7,1,5,0)$ has $\bf0$ projection on $V$. Alternatively, you can solve $(b)$ first and show that the matrix of $T$ isn't invertible, that is, $\text{rank}([T])<4$.

For part $(b)$, let $\mathbf v=(x,y,z,w)\in\Bbb R^4$. The basis $B=\{\mathbf a,\mathbf c\}$ of $V$ consists of orthogonal linearly independent vectors, so the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf v=(x,y,z,w)$ on $V$ is the vector sum $$\displaystyle\frac{\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf a\rangle}{\langle\mathbf a,\mathbf a\rangle}\cdot\mathbf a+\frac{\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf c\rangle}{\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf c\rangle}\cdot\mathbf c$$

Note that you are only able to do this because the basis vectors are orthogonal.

This gives the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf v=(x,y,z,w)$ as

$\displaystyle=\Big[\frac{x-2y-z+3w}{15}\Big]\cdot(1,-2,-1,3)+\Big[\frac{2x+y-3z-w}{15}\Big]\cdot(2,1,-3,-1)\\\displaystyle=\Big(\frac{5x-7z+w}{15},\frac{5y-z-7w}{15},\frac{-7x-y+10z}{15},\frac{x-7y+10w}{15}\Big)$

Thus, the matrix of $T,[T]=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&0&-7/15&1/15\\0&1/3&-1/15&-7/15\\-7/15&-1/15&2/3&0\\1/15&-7/15&0&2/3\end{bmatrix}$.

**Edit.** As hinted by you in a comment, we can show that $T$ is not invertible by noting that the range $R(T)$ is two-dimensional, so nullity of $T>0$.

Comment: Okay. Most of that made sense but I'm still stuck on part $(a)$. How are you able to show that $\mathbf{u}$ has a projection of $0$ in the direction of $V$? Like, how are you physically calculating that out? The way I learned to do orthogonal projections was to use least squares but I never learned other ways.

Comment: I just read your comment on the original post. You gave a fine reasoning for $T$ not being invertible: it is not onto. In other words, its range $R(T)$ is two-dimensional, so the rank of $[T]$, which is nothing but the dimension of the range of $T$, is $2$. This means the nullity of $T=2>0$, so $T$ is not invertible.

Comment: As for how I calculated $\bf u$, recall that the cross-product of two vectors gives you a vector that is orthogonal to both the vectors. A vector that is orthogonal to another vector has $\bf0$ projection along the latter. But this orthogonality property of the cross-product doesn't exist for vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. So I took the cross-product of the first $3$ co-ordinates of the basis vectors of $A$, and made the fourth co-ordinate of $\bf u$ zero.

Comment: As for why $\bf u$ has $\bf0$ projection on $V$, you know that any vector in $V$ can be written as $c_1\mathbf a+c_2\mathbf b$, so $\langle\mathbf u,c_1\mathbf a+c_2\mathbf b\rangle=c_1\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf a\rangle+c_2\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf b\rangle=0+0$

Comment: Okay. Another question. How come you picked $\displaystyle\frac{\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf a\rangle}{\langle\mathbf a,\mathbf a\rangle}\cdot\mathbf a+\frac{\langle\mathbf v,\mathbf b\rangle}{\langle\mathbf b,\mathbf b\rangle}\cdot\mathbf b$ ?

I know that is the definition of projection but why did you not pick $\mathbf{c}$ or $\mathbf{d}$ in the projection? How did you obtain that projection formula?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I edited my question because I mislabeled some vectors. Luckily, the answer is not affected.

Comment: Let's say we have any two basis vectors $\bf v_1,v_2$ of $V$. Then the projection of $\bf u$ along $\bf v_1$ is $\displaystyle\frac{\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf{v_1}\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_1}\rangle}\cdot\mathbf{v_1}$ and similarly for its projection along $\bf v_2$. But in general, the projection of $\bf u$ on $V$ is not equal to $\displaystyle\frac{\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf{v_1}\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_1}\rangle}\cdot\mathbf{v_1}+\displaystyle\frac{\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf{v_2}\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{v_2},\mathbf{v_2}\rangle}\cdot\mathbf{v_2}$.

Comment: For this to happen, $\bf v_1,v_2$ must be orthogonal. The only basis containing orthogonal linearly independent vectors is $A$

Comment: To see why, you know that the orthogonal projection of $\bf u$ on $V$ is a vector in $V$, so it can be written as a linear combination of $\bf v_1,v_2$$\implies \mathbf u=k_1\mathbf{v_1}+k_2\mathbf{v_2}$. We need to find $k_i$. If we are given that $\bf v_1,v_2$ are orthogonal, we have $\bf\langle u,v_1\rangle$$=\langle k_1\mathbf {v_1}+k_2\mathbf{v_2}, \mathbf {v_1}\rangle=k_1\langle\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_1}\rangle+0\implies k_1=\displaystyle\frac{\bf\langle u,v_1\rangle}{\bf\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}$.

Comment: Similarly, take the inner product of $\bf u$ with $\bf v_2$ to get $k_2=\displaystyle\frac{\bf\langle u,v_2\rangle}{\bf\langle v_2,v_2\rangle}$

Comment: Okay. I've finally understood almost all of it. However, how is $A$ consisting of orthogonal vectors? $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}$ is not $0$.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say $B$, as I wrote in my answer. It is $B$ that has the orthogonal vectors

Comment: This finally makes sense. Thank you so much for your patience and help! I really appreciate it! I'm relearning linear algebra completely from scratch since I did so poorly in it the first time and even though I made it through, I want a good, through knowledge of it since I enjoy mathematics so I've been doing a bunch of questions for review.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck to you!

Comment: @FutureMathperson A little warning: I just read my previous comments and there is a little error:  I denoted the orthogonal projection of $\bf u$ on $V$ as $\bf u$. I hope you caught that. It is hard handling all this Mathjax for writing puny expressions. Errors creep in when I blindly copy and paste lines of code

Comment: Ohh one last thing. Does the fact that it said an "ordered basis" mean anything? Is that why we were able to pick the basis vectors which were orthogonal?

Comment: Here, we only have to use the bases to determine the subspace $V$. Part $(b)$ specifically wants the matrix of $T$ in standard co-ordinates for both the domain and range. So the order of the bases $A,B,C$ is immaterial, as co-ordinates are not (and cannot be) expressed with respect to these bases, rather the standard (ordered) basis $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$